# Find top by values by percents using range in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

What will be easier way to group records by range of percents.

Here what I try to accomplish

```
Select top percents between 50 and 75 * from myTable order by PKI
```

Here is way I did this but I have felling that it cloud be much much easier

```
select 
    top(25) percent 
     *
from myTable
where id not in (
            select 
                top(25) percent 
                 ID
            from myTable
            order by PKI
            )
order by PKI
```

This should be top 50 - 75 percents of my table ?

Is there better (nicer) way to do this.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith 2008R2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way of doing it would be

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT ID,
                PKI,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY PKI) AS RN,
                COUNT(*) OVER()                   AS Cnt
         FROM   myTable)
SELECT ID,
       PKI
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RN BETWEEN 0.5 * Cnt AND 0.75 * Cnt
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way would be the use of **[`NTILE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx)** function:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT id,
           pki,
           NTILE(4) OVER(ORDER BY pki) AS quartile
    FROM  myTable
  )
SELECT id,
       pki
FROM  cte
WHERE quartile = 3 ;
```

Comment: That doesn't always return the same as a percentage based calculation would but I guess with only 4 buckets it would be fine (the issue is that if the number of rows is not evenly divisible by number of buckets the extra ones all get added to the first buckets)

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, this behaviour can give rather strange results when the number of rows is small and the NTILE parameter big.